# Updating package version in Xcode Package Manager causes corrupt Package.resolve file

Tags: swift, xcode

I've been going thru various threads but haven't found one that matches my scenario.

After updating a package version, Xcode modified the Package.resolve file by removing the "object": { at the top of the file, then renames the identities of all of the packages to something different and updated the file version. I've deleted the Package.resolve file, went thru File > Packages and tried the 'Rest Package cache' and 'Resolve Package Version' but neither corrected the file format. I'm running Xcode 13.3.1. Has anyone else run into this issue?

[image]

Comment: Did the version value change from 2 to 1?

Comment: I didn't modify any of the XML but with the latest version of Xcode it appears to valid. In the previous version there was a closing brace left over from the Objects identifier. I'm now wondering if Apple just updated the format for the package.resolve and calling it version 2. I didn't see anything in their release notes.

Comment: It appears that recent change in SwiftPM5.6 is causing this issue but has been fixed in new release as they moved to version 2, base on chatter in the SwiftForum: https://forums.swift.org/t/using-swiftpm-5-6-and-supporting-older-versions/55708/5